# Java Stream API : what kind of map method collect(Collectors.toMap()) returns?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

What kind of map  "hm" is?

```
 Map<String,Person> hm;

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("person.txt")) {
        hm = br.lines().map(s -> s.split(","))
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0] , a -> new Person(a[0],a[1],Integer.valueOf(a[2]),Integer.valueOf(a[3]))));
```

Does it depend on declaration?

```
Map<String,Person> hm = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,Person> hm = new TreeMap<>();
```

Comment: A `Map`, *ergo* not a `List` or `Set`.

Comment: The question is corrected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, initializing the variable referenced by `hm` is pointless, since the stream pipeline creates a new `Map` instance, which you then assign to `hm`.

The actual returned `Map` implementation is an implementation detail. Currently it returns a `HashMap` by default, but you can request a specific `Map` implementation by using a different variant of `toMap()`.

You can see one implementation here:

```
public static <T, K, U>
Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                                Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper) {
    return toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, throwingMerger(), HashMap::new);
}
```

You can see that it passes a method reference to a `HashMap` constructor, which means a `HashMap` instance will be created. If you call the 4 argument `toMap` variant, you can control the type of `Map` implementation to be returned.

Similarly, `toList()` returns an `ArrayList` and `toSet` a `HashSet` (at least in Java 8), but that can change in future versions, since it's not part of the contract.

Comment: Interestingly [the documentation of `toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) contains the explicit statement: “*There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned*” and likewise has `toSet()`, but for `toMap(…)` it has been forgotten… [The most recent version](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) has such a statement.