# How to convert a csv into HashMap with java streams without creating entry in intermediate operation?

Tags: java, junit, java-stream

I'm writing a `junit` test where I want to import the expected result from a csv file, as a `HashMap`.

The following works, but I find it kind boilerplate that I first create a `MapEntry.entry()`, which I than collect into a new `HashMap`.

csv:

```
#key;amount
key1;val1
key2;val2
...
keyN;valN
```

test:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> expected = Files.readAllLines(
        Paths.get("test.csv"))
            .stream()
            .map(line -> MapEntry.entry(line.split(",")[0], line.split(",")[1]))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, item -> new BigDecimal(item.getValue())));
```

Especially I'm looking for a oneliner solution like this. I mean: can I prevent having to create a `MapEntry.entry` explicit before again collecting it to a hashmap?

Can this be done better? Or is there even any junit utility that can already read a csv?

Comment: For me this is already a one-line solution.

Comment: You can always have a utility class/method for doing this if it's commonly done in your tests. Then it would become truly a one-line :)

Comment: By the way, do you exactly need a HashMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create entry, you can split the line into array using `map` function and then use `Collectors.toMap`

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> expected = Files.readAllLines(
    Paths.get("test.csv"))
        .stream()
        .map(line->line.split(","))
        .filter(line->line.length>1)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(key->key[0], value -> new BigDecimal(value[1])));
```

If you want to collect entries into a specific type you can use overloaded [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) with `mapSupplier`

> Returns a Collector that accumulates elements into a Map whose keys and values are the result of applying the provided mapping functions to the input elements.

```
 HashMap<String, BigDecimal> expected = Files.readAllLines(
            Paths.get("test.csv"))
            .stream()
            .map(line->line.split(","))
            .filter(line->line.length>1)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(key->key[0], value -> new BigDecimal(value[1]),(val1,val2)->val1, HashMap::new));
}
```

Comment: is Collectors.toMap guaranteed to be a HashMap? since OP specified HashMap.

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed.  Specifiying a supplier is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks @WJS i learned it from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56751993/java-stream-api-what-kind-of-map-method-collectcollectors-tomap-returns

Comment: @WJS where is that guaranteed? I do not see that in the Javadoc. And you would still have to cast it of you need to assign it to a HashMap.

Comment: It's not in the java doc.  It's guaranteed because 1) It's in the API code and 2) as such you can cast the result to `java.util.HashMap`.  So if they ever change it they could break lots of code.

Comment: Yes, the point is that it can change in future implementation and break your code. It is bad practice to rely on such implementation details.

Comment: And the fact that it might be changed in future means that it is not guaranteed. A guarantee is always about future things.

Comment: Yep.  But it's done all the time.  Look at all the code that makes use of properties that aren't advertised in the JavaDoc that are actually recommended in the UI tutorials.  They need to update the JavaDoc to support defacto usage in these situations.

Comment: It is still bad practice to do so, there is a way to specify a supplier so you don't have to cast. That shall be mentioned in the post.

Comment: @Deadpool the last code snipped should be `HashMap<String, BigDecimal> expected`

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> result = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("test.csv"))
.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(l -> l.split(",")[0], l -> new BigDecimal(l.split(",")[1])));
```